# How to run only one test in tox?

Tags: python, tox

I'm trying to write a new test for a project and I'd like to test only that one test in tox. I'm already completely sure that other tests are fine, I don't need them being run every time. The only [suggestion](http://blog.jasonmeridth.com/posts/how-to-run-a-single-test-with-tox/) I've found doesn't work with

```
ERROR: InvocationError: could not find executable
```

Answer (score 69, accepted):

As written by [jason meridth](https://blog.jasonmeridth.com/posts/how-to-run-a-single-test-with-tox/):

```
$ tox -e py35 -- project/tests/test_file.py::TestClassName::test_method
```

But the fine grain is mentioned by [beluga.me](https://stackoverflow.com/users/640916/beluga-me) in the comments: If you have a `tox.ini` file you might need to add the [`{posargs}` to pytest in tox.ini](https://tox.readthedocs.io/en/latest/example/general.html#interactively-passing-positional-arguments):

```
[tox]
envlist = py35

[testenv]
deps =
    pytest
    pytest-cov
    pytest-pep8
commands =
    pip install -e .
    pytest {posargs}
```

### Run one test with unittest

```
python3 -m unittest -q test_file.TestClassName
```

Answer (score 9):

Run this command:

```
tox -epy27 -- test_name
```

for [more information](https://wiki.openstack.org/wiki/Testr#Writing_Tests_for_testr).

Comment: I can't make this work for me with either tox 2.6 or 2.7, it will always run all tests even with e.g. `tox -e py27-django18 -- idontexistatall`

Comment: Found my issue, one should have a close look at the tox.ini, if the `commands =` doesn't have a `{posargs}` it will disregard whatever you add to your command.

Answer (score 0):

pytest -k <<<test_name>> will work